# JSON Line Break Whitespace in Python

Tags: python, json, api

I've seen some similar questions, but not quite what I'm asking (that I could find at least). I'm using the bottom three lines of code to make an api request that returns various aspects of an article.

```
    response = requests.get(self.format_url(api, version), params=payload)
    json_data = response.json()
    return json_data
```

The data I request comes back fine, and I've figured out how to extract the text parameter like I want. The only problem is I want to preserve paragraph breaks, but `article_text` below is just all the text having ignored paragraph breaks. Is there a standard way to do this with json or is it completely dependent on the API I'm using? Thanks for your help, I'm new to python!

```
    article_text = json_data['objects'][0]['text']
```

Comment: How do you know that there are no paragraph breaks?

Comment: That's a good question actually. I'm posting the content I pull onto a website. I checked the mobile and desktop versions though. On mobile the content looks fine, but on desktop it does not. I can see where paragraph breaks should be because it does start a new line, but there's no actual space between the two paragraphs.

Comment: Check the webpage source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone happens to read this, the solution I implemented was to pull the unaltered html from `json_data` then utilize beautiful soup to format the text by searching for all

tags and replacing them with 
 tags. That worked.